# Properly Terminating stream for SaxParser, avoiding "unexpected end of file" exception

Tags: android, xml, saxparser, saxparseexception

I am having the same problem to the one quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239361/saxparser-on-android-unexpected-end-of-document-exception) on Android.

The solution given was to use a URI rather than the inputstream.

I believe that you can use an inputStream as the API indicates but obviously there is something wrong with the stream that is raising exceptions with the parse method. I can confirm all the data is going into the stream, and the SAXParseException indicates that all the data is going to the parse method as I can use getColumnNumber method which returns -1, (indicating the entire stream has been read). But it looks like the parse method is not acknowledging this as the end of the stream, thus raising the "Unexpected end of file" (?)

Can someone please advise how to use an inputstream rather than the URI as input to the parse method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem but the cause was that I was accepting the inputstream in the wrong encoding format. Make sure that you put it in the right encoding first (maybe by reading it in as a byte[] and using the String(byte[], String) constructor) and then try and put it through the SAX parser.

And if you want to parse XML in Android maybe you would be better off using the [Simple library in Android](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).

Comment: Would "UTF8" be the most common setting to use ? Which one did you use ? I am looking for a list of charsets accepted by inputstreamreader. Would this link be a the correct source ? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: Thnx. I added encoding like this, InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sData.getBytes("UTF-8"));  and it worked. However, I have did have to omit an internal schema listed in the bytestream, ie. <!DOCTYPE.... as it kept raising an exception. But once I just sent straight XML, it was all good.

Comment: Glad that helped, it is an odd problem and I think there is something that I am missing that makes this happen. Either way I think it is better to just be safe in the selection of encoding formats before passing the raw data to the parser.